# how use image fields in django1.6.2

Tags: django

imagefield for django 1.6.2

i have a code that can uploat any file by it and work currectly:

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

but when i changed filefield to imagefield :

```
class Document(models.Model):
docfile = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

[image]

what is the problem ?

Comment: If you've read the error, you would've seen it very clearly tells you that you need to install the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (otherwise known as PIL), or it's fork [Pillow](http://python-imaging.github.io/)

Comment: The current free version is PIL 1.1.7(November 15, 2009). This release supports Python 1.5.2 and newer, including 2.5 and 2.6. A version for 3.X will be released later. it means pil dosent work wite 3.x ? i use python 3.3. what should i do ?

Comment: As I've mentioned, you can also install [Pillow](http://python-imaging.github.io/). It's newer, and even though PIL is officially not dead yet, it's probably [going to soon](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html#what-about-pil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this program do that django1.6.2 imagefield :[github](https://github.com/mrpd/djangouploadimage)